How do I add multiple lines in the body of an outlook appointment created in access using vba
This is an extract of the code I used to create the appointment:
With itmAppoint

    .Subject = Me.txtTechCode + " = " + Me.txtClientName
    .Start = Me.txtAppDate + Me.txtAppTime
    .End = Me.txtAppDate + Me.txtAppTime + Me.txtAppDuration
    '   .Location = Me.ActionLocation
    .Body = "Client Name:" + " " + txtClientName + " " + "Contact Person:" + " " + txtContactPerson
    .Recipients.Add ("abc@def.com")
    .Recipients.ResolveAll

    .Save ' <- this actually sends the appointment to Outlook

End With

I have many more fields from the access form that I woudl like to add to the body of the appointment but not in a straight line but rather one field per line.

Ampersand character is preferred for text concatenation in Access and VBA. Unless you want to take advantage of special aspect of concatenation with plus sign - if field is Null, the result of concatenation will be Null.
Not quite sure what you mean by "one field per line". If you want to save text with embedded carriage return line feed, concatenate vbCrLf. If you meant code should be multi-line so it is more readable, options are:

use underscore line continuation character where you want line to break

.Body = "Client Name: " & txtClientName & vbCrLf & _
        "Contact Person: " & txtContactPerson


concatenate multiple lines into a variable - .Body could serve as the variable or declare a string variable then set .Body to that variable at the end

.Body = .Body & "Client Name: " & txtClientName & vbCrLf
.Body = .Body & "Contact Person: " & txtContactPerson


You can use my Build function
Function Build(ByVal s As String, ParamArray args()) As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    s = Replace(s, "\n", vbCrLf)
    For i = 0 To UBound(args)
        s = Replace(s, "{" & i & "}", Nz(args(i)))
    Next i
    Build = s
End Function

Call:
.Body = Build("Client Name: {0}\nContact Person: {1}", "The Company", "Smith")

result:
Client Name: The Company
Contact Person: Smith

Use placeholders starting with {0} and incrementing the number by 1 up to the number of parameters following the format string minus 1.
Occurrences of \n will be replaced by vbCrLf.
